# How to allow only one link in a list to activate its pop only while disabling other links

Tags: jquery, popup, modal-dialog

I have a list of links to display a div pop-up which shows additional content however clicking each link will display its individual pop-up resulting in multiple pop-ups open at once. How can I prevent the other links from displaying there pop-up if one link which as has already been clicked displayed its pop-up until the pop-up window is closed.

I've tried the following code:

```
jQuery('a.portfoliobtn').click(function() {
    jQuery(this).addClass('active');

    jQuery('a.portfoliobtn').addClass('notactive');

    if (jQuery(this).hasClass('notactive')) {
        alert("yes")

        return false;


    }else {
        return false;
        }
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="cat-7" class="cat-list">    
<a class="portfoliobtn" href="#modal_7" role="button" data-toggle="modal"><div class="cat-title"><i class="fa fa-bullhorn fa-5x"></i> Advertising </div> </a>   

        <div id="modal_7" class="modal hide" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

        <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" title="Close" aria-hidden="true">X</button>
                <h3 id="myModalLabel">Advertising</h3>
            </div>



            <li id="post-48" class="list-item clearfix">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="thumb-box"><img width="792" height="612" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="Adolfo-Dominguez" /></div>

                </div>

            </li>    




            <li id="post-55" class="list-item clearfix">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="thumb-box"><img width="792" height="612" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="caribbean-airlines" /></div>

                </div>

            </li>    




            <li id="post-63" class="list-item clearfix">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="thumb-box"><img width="374" height="149" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="ClickMedia" /></div>

                </div>

            </li>    




            <li id="post-161" class="list-item clearfix">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="thumb-box"><img width="359" height="127" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="Lonsdale-Saatchi-&amp;-Saatchi" /></div>

                </div>

            </li>    


                </div>

    </ul>
```

Airlines and Travel    

    

    
            X
            Airlines and Travel

Comment: Can you be more specific? And please include some HTML

Comment: Are you using the jQuery ui modal?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're on `bootstrap 2.3.2` in `bootstrap 3` it's different so let me know.

```
var modalOpen = false;

$('.modal').on('show', function () {
    modalOpen = true;
});
$('.modal').on('hidden', function () {
    modalOpen = false;
})     

jQuery('a.portfoliobtn').click(function(event) {
    if(modalOpen)
        return false;
});
```

Comment: I solved it I just updated to bootstrap 3 thanks for the help

Comment: @Oudin Your welcome, please upvote and or mark this answer as accepted if it helped you answer your question.